# How to change gauge chart in apache echarts color will gradient

Tags: angular, echarts, apache-echarts

I am changinf the gauge chart color but color is changeing but not gradient. Can any one suggest me how to change gradient color. Please find the screenshot which required for me.
[image]

But apache echarts is not option for gradient color in gauge chart. its is showing
[image]

Please suggest me how is it possible. I will use in angular 13.1.0 version code.

Comment: have you had a look at this part of the documentation

https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#color.  &. https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-gauge.data.itemStyle.color